# Given an arbitrary number of points, how do you find an equidistant center?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, coordinate-systems

Given an arbitrary set of points on a Cartesian coordinate plane, is there a generalized formula to find the **closest** point that is equidistant from all the given points?

My first guess was finding the centroid, which is fairly easy to calculate, but the centroid of a polygon isn't equidistant from all its vertices.

Comment: Consider the points (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), in the plane. No point is equidistant from these points. Have I missed something in the definitions?

Comment: For an arbitrary set of points, it may not exist...

Comment: It is not clear to me what the point should do. Should it minimize the maximum distance?

Comment: So given some $\epsilon \gt 0$ and points $P_1, P_2, \dots P_n$, you want a point $P_{\epsilon}$ such that $|D(P_{\epsilon},P_i) - D(P_{\epsilon},P_j)| \lt \epsilon$, if it exists and then try to "minimize" $\epsilon$ and find a corresponding $P_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize that it could be impossible to find an equidistant point...

Aryabhata, that sounds about right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no point that is equidistant from 4 or more points in general position in the plane, or $n+2$ points in $n$ dimensions.

Criteria for representing a collection of points by one point are considered in statistics, machine learning, and computer science.  The centroid is the optimal choice in the least-squares sense, but there are many other possibilities.

Added to answer the comment:

The centroid is the point $C$ in the the plane for which the sum of squared distances $\sum |CP_i|^2$ is minimum.  One could also optimize a different measure of centrality, or insist that the representative be one of the points (such as a graph-theoretic center of a weighted spanning tree), or assign weights to the points in some fashion and take the centroid of those.

Comment: What does "least-squares" mean? And what are some alternatives to the centroid?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the question asks for a method to find a point equidistant to a given set of points and the accepted answer claims that the centroid provides the answer in the "least-squares sense", it seems appropriate to present the actual least-squares solution.

Let the cost-function be:
$$
\tilde{y}_i = \lvert\lvert x_i-\hat{x}_c\rvert\rvert_2 - \hat{r}_c
$$
Where $x_i$ is the Cartesian coordinate of the $i^{th}$ point in the set, $\hat{x}_c$ is the estimated "equidistant center", and $\hat{r}_c$ is the estimated distance between $\hat{x}_c$ and all other points $x_i$.

The Jacobian of $\tilde{y}_i$ with respect to the desired state $\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}_c \\ \hat{r}_c \end{bmatrix}$ is:
$$
H_{i,12} = -\frac{(x_i - \hat{x}_c)}{\lvert\lvert x_i - \hat{x}_c\rvert\rvert_2}
$$

$$
H_{i,3} = -1
$$

Where $H$ is a $N_p \times 3$ matrix ($N_p$ is the number of 2D Cartesian points), $H_{i,12}$ is the first two columns of the $i^{th}$ row, and $H_{i,3}$ is the third column of the $i^{th}$ row.

Let:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x}_c \\
\hat{r}_c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
be the stacked state vector. A single least-squares update looks like:

$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k+1} = \hat{\mathbf{x}}_k - (H^T H)^{-1} H^T \tilde{y}
$$

The least-squares estimate to the question can be calculated by initializing $\mathbf{x}_{k=0}$ with an initial guess (perhaps involving the centroid) and iteratively updating $\tilde{y}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$.

This is the answer in the least-squares sense.

This set of 6 points:

$x = \lbrace[443.292, 397.164], [355.53, 349.168], [326.975, 253.249], [562.139, 186.385], [375.017, 165.456], [473.424, 137.604]\rbrace$

has a ``least-squares equidistant center'' of $[457.9097, 267.1183]$ with a point separation of $131.1977$.

Their centroid is $[422.7295, 248.1710]$.

Note that the given points are 6 of 8 equally spaced points around a circle (i.e., 2 are missing) and the least-squares solution recovers both the center of the circle and its radius. This is a case where the question has a clear answer.

This is not the centroid of these points and, no, the centroid does not answer the question in a "least-squares sense" either.